# How do I populate two fields in a table from picking an option in a further field?

Tags: ms-access, field, auto-populate

I have a group of tables that are linked together.

I have a table called `Guests` and one called `Payments`.

The `Guest` table has 3 fields: `ID`, `Firstname`, `Lastname`.

The `Payments` table has 6 fields: `Invoicenumber`, `ID`, `Firstname`, `Lastname`, `Service`, `price`.

I have it setup, so when I click on `ID`, it yields me a list of people from the `Guests` table by their `ID`, then `Firstname`, `Lastname`. So this way I can pick the right `ID` number to attach to the `Payments` table. However I can't get the `Firstname` and `Lastname` on the the `Payments` table to populate from the details in the `Guest` table. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Create combobox with 3 columns, based on Guests table. 
In `AfterUpdate' event of this combobox add code for coping of data from 2nd and 3rd columns of combobox to Firstname and Lastname fields of Payments table:

```
[Firstname] = Me.txtID.Column(1)
[Lastname] = Me.txtID.Column(2)
```